# Help with an implication of a really basic question in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm starting to study algebraic geometry and I'm trying to prove this implication:

> For a homogeneous ideal $\mathfrak a\subset S$, show that $Z(\mathfrak
>  a)=\emptyset \implies \sqrt {\mathfrak a}=\text{either}\ S \ \text{or
>  the ideal}\ S_+=\bigoplus_{d\gt0}S_d$.

I have seeing somewhere that this is true because of these implications:

$Z(\mathfrak a)$ is empty $\implies$ in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$, $Z(\mathfrak a)$ must be empty or $(0,\ldots 0) \implies \sqrt{\mathfrak a}=S$ or $\sqrt{\mathfrak a}=\bigoplus_{d\gt 0} S_d$.

I don't understand both implications, I would appreciate if someone could help me, I really need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $S=k[x_0,...,x_n]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. This is exactly your setup, no?

Anyways, the homogeneous ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset S$ defines a projective algebraic set $Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a}) \subset \Bbb P^n$. But $\mathfrak{a}$ is also an honest ideal of the polynomial ring $k[x_0,...,x_n]$, hence it also defines an affine algebraic set
$$
Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a}) \subset \Bbb A^{n+1}
$$

Note that by construction $\Bbb P^n$ is a quotient of $\Bbb A^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. Denote by $[P] \in \Bbb P^n$ the residue class of $P \in \Bbb A^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$.

Now if $P \in Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})$ and $P \neq 0$, then $[P] \in Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a})$, so if $Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a})$ is empty then either $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})$ is empty as well, or $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})=\{0\}$.

The second implication follows from the well-known order preserving bijection between radical ideals and affine algebraic sets over an algebraically closed field, which in turn follows from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. In particular, if $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})=\emptyset$ then
$$
\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=\mathfrak{a}=S
$$
and if $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})=\{0\}$ then
$$
\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=(x_0,...,x_n)=\bigoplus_{d>0}S_d
$$

Comment: $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak a)$ can be empty? the definition of the $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak a)$ is that one: $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak a)=\{(x_1,..., x_n)/[x_1,...,x_n]\in Z^{proj}$ or $(x_1,..., x_n)=(0,...,0)\}$?

Comment: Dear @user42912, sorry, I didn't realize that my wording was ambiguous. By $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})$ I meant the common vanishing locus of the $f \in \mathfrak{a}$ (which can be empty). I called it *cone*, because if $Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a})$ is not empty, then $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})$ *is* the cone of $Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a})$. But here we are considering $Z^{proj}(\mathfrak{a})=\emptyset$, and the cone is usually defined only for non-empty projective algebraic sets (probably in order to prevent exactly the same sort of confusion it causes here). Does that clear things up?

Comment: yes, now this part is ok, thank you.

Comment: but the second implication remains mysterious to me. If you can add something more, I would appreciate very much.

Comment: I think I understood what you said in the second part of the second implication, but why in the first part if $Z^{aff}(\mathfrak{a})=\emptyset$ then

$\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=\mathfrak{a}=S
$?

Comment: Dear @user42912, as I said this follows quite directly from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, which is probably one of the most important results in algebraic geometry. I don't know from which sources you learn algebraic geometry, but if these don't mention Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, then I would look for different sources.

Comment: yes, I know Hilbert's Nullstellensatz,but I couldn't see why $\sqrt a=a=S$

Comment: Dear @user42912, a corollary of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is that if $\mathfrak{a} \subset k[x_0,...,x_n]$ is a proper ideal, with $k$ algebraically closed, then $Z(\mathfrak{a}) \neq \emptyset$. The statement you're asking about is the contrapositive of that.

Comment: yes, of course. Thank you for helping me and for the patience.

Comment: Dear @user42912, you're welcome.